# How to get current retry count in cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

i was using **@ExtendedCucumberOptions** in my runner class where i can give retry count, if my test Scenario fails i was try to re run it according the count which i have given in this runner file but here i wants to know in middle of my Scenario i need to get or know what is the retry count value

Runner class as below and i was using mkolisnyk dependency in pom :

```
@ExtendedCucumberOptions(
        jsonReport = "target/81/cucumber.json",
        retryCount = 3)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = { "src/test/java/com/github/mkolisnyk/cucumber/features/Test.feature" },
        tags = { "@failed" },
        glue = "com/github/mkolisnyk/cucumber/steps", plugin = {
        "html:target/81", "json:target/81/cucumber.json",
        "pretty:target/81/cucumber-pretty.txt",
        "usage:target/81/cucumber-usage.json", "junit:target/81/cucumber-results.xml" })
public static class SampleTestRetry {
}
```

eg: here i have kept **retryCount** as 3 right i have started executing one of the Scenario  in my suite for the 1st time it got failed and started retrying so i middle of before class i wants to fetch the count of retry right now ..so i need help on this i was not able to fetch the **retryCount** in the middle ot my test cases so please help me on this .